# Durundal Bootstrap Themes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal

I am looking to apply bootstrap themes from http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#bootswatch_tab.

So I have View Model : Shell and VIew as below ,I am using Ko.Observable array to load all theme names require to be displayed in Bootstrap Drop-down but Drop-down is not populating with the observable values

Please help me to resolve. Thanks in Advance

**shell.js**

```
define(['durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
    function (system, router, logger , config) {


var themes =  ko.observableArray([
                 { key: "amelia", text: "Amelia" },
                { key: "cerulean", text: "Cerulean" },
                { key: "cosmo", text: "Cosmo" },
                { key: "cyborg", text: "Cyborg" },
                { key: "flatly", text: "Flatly" },
                { key: "journal", text: "Journal" },
                { key: "readable", text: "Readable" },
                { key: "simplex", text: "Simplex" },
                { key: "slate", text: "Slate" },
                { key: "spacelab", text: "Spacelab" },
                { key: "united", text: "United" }
    ]);
        var shell = {
            activate: activate,
            router: router,
            themes: themes
        };

        return shell;

        //#region Internal Methods
        function activate() {
         return boot();
        }


        function boot() {
            log(config.appTitle + 'Loaded!', null, true);

            router.on('router:route:not-found', function (fragment) {
                logError('No Route Found', fragment, true);
            });

            var routes = [
                { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'Home', nav: 1 },
                { route: 'details', moduleId: 'details', title: 'Details', nav: 2 }];

            return router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' }) // router will look here for viewmodels by convention
                .map(routes)            // Map the routes
                .buildNavigationModel() // Finds all nav routes and readies them
                .activate();            // Activate the router
        }

        function log(msg, data, showToast) {
            logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
        }

        function logError(msg, data, showToast) {
            logger.logError(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
        }
        //#endregion
    });
```

**View Shell.html**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="/">
                <span class="title">Hot Towel SPA</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
                <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<!-- Load Themes -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="themes" data-bind="foreach: themes">
                        <li>
                            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: text"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
                <div class="progress progress-striped active page-progress-bar">
                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is not with binding but in the CSS, I have updated some CSS classes (especially nav-collapse in line 13 and 4 ), now the dropdown appears

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="/">
                <span class="title">Hot Towel SPA</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
                <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<!-- Load Themes -->
            <ul class="nav navbar">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="themes" data-bind="foreach: themes">
                        <li>
                            <a data-bind="attr: { href: key }, text: text"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
                <div class="progress progress-striped active page-progress-bar">
                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Btw, you still have problems with what happens when you click an item in the drop down, I have just mapped it to key as there is no `hash` as mentioned by @Matthew James Davis

Comment: But Durundal2.0 Template Shell coming with Hash

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel"><li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }"> <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a></li></ul>

Comment: yes that is fine, but below that you are listing the themes as dropdown,<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="themes" data-bind="foreach: themes">
                        <li>
                            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: text"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>  , you need to add hash property to items in themes array, which i guess would point to your css files

Comment: Thank you! I spend hours trying to figure out how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be logged in your console as an error.

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: text"></a>
```

Hash is not defined. You want:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '#/' + key }, text: text"></a>
```